# How to open the email dialog with a StringBuilder attached as XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, email, stringbuilder

I made a StringBuilder in C#(asp.net) which has an xml structure, using this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
    sb.AppendLine("<form>");

    foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
        sb.Append("<" + c.ID + ">");
        sb.Append(((TextBox)c).Text);
        sb.AppendLine("</" + c.ID + ">");
        }

    }

    sb.Append("</form>");
```

How do I continue the code so it open the mail dialog with the StringBuilder attached as XML?